# Cannot install Windows Subsystem for Linux, error 0x800f0831

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My installation of WSL fails with error 0x800f0831 when I try it either via powershell or via enable optional features.

Windows 1809, build 17763.678

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature failed. Error code = 0x800f0831
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

I've run the following commands as suggested by some technet articles, but to no avail:

```
sfc /scannow
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sc config wuauserv start=disabled 
net stop bits
net stop appidsvc
net stop cryptsvc
net stop wuauserv
net stop wuauserv
rd /q /s %Systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution
rd /q /s %Systemroot%\system32\catroot2
del %Systemroot%\WindowsUpdate.log
sc config wuauserv start=auto  
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow
```

Any thoughts on how to move forward with this?

Comment: The best working solution for 3 years is -- reinstall Windows 10 OS.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this...

Comment: Have you tried using the GUI? In Add/Remove Windows Features?

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez, yes -- same error.

Comment: Your Windows is a corporate one? If not you can try to upgrade it to 1903, maybe it fixes the corruption

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez you're absolutely right. I upgraded to 1903 and then the installation process went through without any issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded Windows 10 from version 1809 to 1903 solved this issue as suggested by CarlosRafaelRamirez in the comments.